# Is there anyway to use v-date-picker in Vue.js as date-time and not only as date?

Tags: datetime, vue.js

What I am trying to do is use only v-date-picker without any other time-pickers. I was wondering if there is any way to change the type of v-date-picker in VueJS to be able to pick also hours, minutes and seconds (besides date). Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use date picker and timepicker from vuetify component library https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/time-pickers

Comment: So there is no way to use date picker to pick the time as well, right?

Comment: Can you please share the link of datetime component library?

Comment: This is what I'm using: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers

Comment: Yes it is possible, but you can customize existing date-picker component to support hours,, minitues, seconds selection

Comment: How? This is what I am asking.

Comment: You need to write some additional code to implement , have you tried something and facing issue. If so share your code, that would be really better to help you out in solving the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with https://github.com/darrenfang/vuetify-datetime-picker

```
<v-datetime-picker label="Select Datetime" v-model="datetime"> </v-datetime-picker>
```

[image: Date selector]

[image: Time selector]

Answer (score 0):

Using the same library referenced by **Jeanpaul1304** [vuetify-datetime-picker](https://github.com/darrenfang/vuetify-datetime-picker)

You can implement it like the following on your component:

```
<v-datetime-picker
    :text-field-props="{prependIcon: 'mdi-calendar'}"
    label="Select Date Time"
    v-model="datetime"
    readonly>
    <template slot="dateIcon">
      <v-icon>mdi mdi-calendar</v-icon>
    </template>
    <template slot="timeIcon">
      <v-icon>mdi mdi-clock</v-icon>
    </template>
</v-datetime-picker>
```

If you're using vuejs with nuxtjs you can add a plugin i.e. *vuetify-datetime-picker.js* and add the following code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import DatetimePicker from 'vuetify-datetime-picker'

Vue.use(DatetimePicker)
```

Then in your *nuxt.config.js* you can add the plugin as so:

```
plugins: [   
    { src: '@/plugins/vuetify-datetime-picker.js', mode: 'client' },
  ],
```