# Time picker not showing in v-date-picker

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to select a time range using v-date-picker on [vCalender](https://vcalendar.io/datepicker.html) in my vuetify project. I use v-date-picker for this. Even though I use dateTime as the mod in v-date-picker, there is no place to select the time. It's just the calendar. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

my-template

```
      <div>
              <div class="flex mb-2">
                <label class="text-gray-600 font-medium"><input class="mr-1" type="radio" value="" v-model="timezone" />Local</label>
                <label class="text-gray-600 font-medium ml-3"><input class="mr-1" type="radio" value="utc" v-model="timezone" />UTC</label>
              </div>
              <v-date-picker v-model="date" multiple :timezone="timezone" mode="dateTime" />
            </div>
```

my data:

```
date: new Date(),
timezone: '',
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

The problem seems to be a conflict as both components are named `v-date-picker`, and as it stands, it is picking the **Vuetify**'s component as the default. If you wish to use both in your application, check [this resolved Github issue](https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar/issues/37):

Quouting the owner of Vcalendar; [nathanreyes](https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar/issues/37#:%7E:text=Owner-,nathanreyes,-commented%20on%20May) from the Github issue:

> You can pass componentPrefix as an option when using VCalendar.
>
> ```
> Vue.use(VCalendar, {
>   componentPrefix: 'vc'
> })
> ```
>
> Then when using in template
>
> ```
> <template>
>   <vc-calendar>
>   </vc-calendar>
> </template>
> ```

*Old answer below is before the OP edited the question to better reflect the problem.*

---

There is no option in the [v-date-picker API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-date-picker/#:%7E:text=picker.%20Called%20with%20date%20(ISO%208601%20date%20string)%20arguments.-,%23,type,-string) for `mode`. However, there *is* a `type` option, but it only supports either "*date*" for date picker or "*month*" for month picker.

You could use [vuetify-datetime-picker](https://github.com/darrenfang/vuetify-datetime-picker) extension of Vuetify instead which was linked in an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58516336/is-there-anyway-to-use-v-date-picker-in-vue-js-as-date-time-and-not-only-as-date) question. Thanks to @[Jeanpaul1304](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3255459/jeanpaul1304).

Comment: actually i am trying to use Vcalender https://vcalendar.io/datepicker.html. I created this code by looking at the code from there, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Vue.use(VCalendar, {
  componentPrefix: 'vc', // Now use vc-calendar and vc-date-picker
});
```

The code is not working because there is confusion with vuetify. For this, we need to make changes in main js. So we need to use vc-data-picker instead of v-data-picker.